# How do I set default values for make?

Tags: compilation, makefile, parallel-processing

I'm the lucky owner of a 8 core Intel CPU, and I compile allot of stuff, mostly with `make`.

To `make` this run fast I usually use the `-j 8` setting, telling make that it can run 8-way parallel -- however, sometimes I forget the `-j 8` and feel the need to start hitting myself as my compilation runs way to slow.

how do I set `-j 8`, and similar stuff as the defaults for `make`?

/Martin

Comment: Which make and platform? GNU on Linux?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: make on OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the environment variable MAKEFLAGS to values you want to have "always set":

```
MAKEFLAGS=-j8
export MAKEFLAGS
```

Comment: is there a way to set it inside that makefile?

Comment: Not for that instance of make.  The set up of parallelism happens right when make first starts up, so by the time the makefile is parsed it's too late.